# Remove Header and Footer using C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on windows application using C#. I generated the "Report" using IE control. While printing and exporting into XPS format, Header and Footer are appearing. But i don't want the header and Footer and also i don't want to touch the IE settings. I want to remove the Header and Footer using C#. So user can print other IE pages with Header and Footer. How to do this.

*Updated:*
Ok, Header and Footer needs to be disabled while printing. I'm using IE browser for displaying the Report and it has three export options( HTML, PDF, XPS). Export to pdf is done using Infragistics document engine. This report has print option also, for this i need to remove Header and Footer while printing.

Comment: You mean the header and footer of your master control? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a PDF report. This way IE (FF etc) has nothing to do with margins and header/footers.

Comment: Customer may don't have Acrobat Reader

Comment: B2B or B2C? If B2B: make it a requirement. If B2C: who doesn't have a PDF reader installed? And if not, give instructions on how to obtain a PDF reader.