# Remove header content in pdf while converting into text format c#

Tags: c#, pdf

I am trying to convert a PDF to Text format,

I used following code which is working fine:

```
string text = null;
 PdfFocus execute = new PdfFocus();
 Uri url = new Uri(letterUrl);          
 execute.OpenPdf(url);
if (execute.PageCount > 0)
 {
  text = execute.ToText(1,1);
 }
```

Can someone help me how to remove the header content in PDF before or after converting?

Comment: What is *header content*? Can you show pdf, text you get and what you want instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431236/remove-header-and-footer-using-c-sharp

Comment: [`PdfFocus.ToText(int, int)` returns a `String`](http://www.sautinsoft.net/help/pdf-to-word-tiff-images-text-rtf-csharp-vb-net/html/33fbdb20-d3d7-36ad-9721-cfe7aebfc88b.htm), so this is just simple text replacement.

Comment: I am getting phone numbers, fax, emai Id's, Address in my PDF footer, I need to remove them before converting to text. is there a method that will remove those footer contents?